# What is the difference between "&=" and "=&" when assigning a variable value in PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I know that `=&` usually means "assign by reference", but what happens if we reverse these two characters, since I've seen this in plenty of PHP scripts?

Comment: `&= ... Logical bitwise AND,
=& ... 'assign' by Reference`

Comment: Have a look in this website [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Comment: Why people think `this question shows research effort;it is useful and clear`?

Comment: @Amir It doesn't necessary have to have research effort, as long as it has the other two qualities you mentioned. I, myself, find the answer to this question pretty useful as a developer. As for clarity, I believe it is written in as clear and simplistic approach possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&=` is a [compound assignment operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/comasse.htm), whereas `=&` is actually two separate operators (`=` and `&`), pushed together. This is legal syntax because PHP doesn't demand whitespace between them.

`&=` performs a bitwise AND operation between the left hand side and right hand side, then assigns the result to the left hand side variable.

```
$x = 1;
$x &= 0; // $x === 0 now. A more verbose syntax would be "$x = $x & 0;"
```

On the other hand
`=&` should really be expanded to `= &` as the operators are seperate. This is known as [assignment by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference). The `=` is your standard assignment operator, and the `&` when prefixed before a variable name returns the `reference` to the variable.

```
$y = "foobar";
$x = &$y; // $x now holds a reference to $y.
```

Answer (score 6):

`$a &= $b` is short for `$a = $a & $b` which is the bitwise-and operator.

Answer (score 5):

It's the compound [bitwise AND](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)/assignment operator:

```
$x = 0x01;
$y = 0x11;

$y &= $x; // bitwise AND $y and $x, assign result back to $y
var_dump($y == 0x01); // true
```